# Thunderbird ISPDB location

Tags: thunderbird

I'm having a problem with the Thunderbird ISPDB, I think my provider is not listed correctly, at least the settings don't work.

Before I post in the Thunderbird mailing list, I would like to manually check the settings.

However, I don't find the database on either my local disk or on github.

Where is it usually located (locally or on the internet)? I did not even find it on Github.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ISP DB is a centrally hosted service by Mozilla. You can see the contents [here](https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/) - it's just flat files named like the domain of the ISP.

Here's the problem: [They make it sound like you have to actually be staff at the ISP to update the database.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration)

> How to add support for your domain
>
> If you are a big ISP (> 100,000 users) providing email addresses
>   solely under a few domains like "example.com" and "example.de", you
>   may either submit the configuration to the ISPDB or set up a
>   configuration server.
>
> If you support email aliases and the user's login name is not part of
>   the email address (for example, users may have "hero@example.com" as
>   email address, but the IMAP/POP/SMTP login name is neither "hero" nor
>   "hero@example.com", but "u67578"), you need to set up a configuration
>   server, which does the email address -> login name lookup.
>
> If you host customer domains, i.e. you are "hoster.com", but your
>   customers have "fred@flintstone.com" and "louis@kent.com" as domains,
>   with only a few users per domain, you need to set up a configuration
>   server (or rely on DNS MX).
>
> If you are a small company installing Thunderbird on your employees'
>   desktops, you can place a configuration file in the Thunderbird
>   installation folder.

In which case, you'd need to talk to your provider to find out how they're sharing that info out.

Comment: Does that mean that I can not inspect the database? I did not find it on the internet.

Comment: There's a link in that article - try https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/. It's just a series of flat files named like domains.